# POST to Android Webview where the response is a PDF file

Tags: android, android-webview

I am performing a POST to the Android webview where the expected response is a PDF file. However the webview just shows a blank page. I realise that PDF files cannot be rendered in the webview but would expect the file to start downloading or show some response at least.

Does anyone know if its possible to POST to a webview to initiate download of a (pdf) file?

```
        _webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.ebookWebview);
        _webView.SetWebViewClient(webviewClient);
        _webView.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        _webView.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
        _webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;

        _webView.PostUrl(_postUrl, EncodingUtils.GetBytes(_postData, "BASE64"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried registering a DownloadListener on the WebView? That is needed to handle the download. Please see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setDownloadListener(android.webkit.DownloadListener)